# Advanced Custom Fields Display All the values in Dropdown Menu

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WordPress CMS..

and I just installed ACF Plugins (Advanced Custom Fields)..
so, I added a field named 'category'..
and I added a dropdown select input and set the choices' value..

and my question is,
how to display all those values?

[image]

So, What im gonna do is something like

```
<?php
  $data_field_array=get_select_field_values('category');
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($data_field_array as $value){
    echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";  
?>
```

the output expected is:

- News & Events
- Roadshow
- Press Release
- Video Gallery

Comment: No use posting an expected outcome... Try it and let us know what the problem is...

Comment: the problem is i dont know the (something like) built-in function for displaying all those values..

based on the ACF documentation, i already tried get_field(), get_fields(), get_field_object(),

but those functions i mentioned above is the field value for a certain post.

But i dont want that.

Comment: I want to display all values based on the custom field created, NOT BASED on a certain POST.

Comment: Did u find an answer for this? if so please post the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`get_field_object()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/) for this:

```
$field = get_field_object('category');
if( $field ) {
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $field['choices'] as $value ) {
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label and value you can use:

```
<?php 
    $field = get_field_object($category); 
    if( $field ){
        foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ){
            echo '<li value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</li>';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Where $field_name is your ACF Machine name of the field

Comment: Can you please post a proper answer